# Facebook SDK how to handle custom login in swift?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am implementing a Facebook login in my app and I just need to store the token for the session but without using the standard Facebook button...

I managed to use:

```
FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithPublishPermissions(["publish_actions"], handler: nil)
```

which works exactly as expected... Now I am learning Swift and I have no knowledge of Obj-C (although it's becoming more and more obvious that I will need some at some point) how do I implement the handler to, say perform

```
println(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken())
```

upon completion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for anyone interested in it...

```
let FBLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

FBLoginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(["publish_actions"], handler: { (response:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) in
    if(error != nil){
        // Handle error
    }
    else if(response.isCancelled){
        // Authorization has been canceled by user
    }
    else {
        // Authorization successful
        // println(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken())
        // no longer necessary as the token is already in the response
        println(response.token.tokenString)
    }
})
```

Comment: Where do you save the token and does it not ask for "You have already authorised " after you save and login for second time because in my case I am not saving and its always says "You have already authorized app name"

Comment: If i want to post photo / message only to me/feed , do i need to get the approval of Facebook? I've tried but didn't succeed